# Are semicolons in PHP optional?

Tags: php, syntax

I know that PHP, just like Java, and C++ use semicolons to terminate statements, so I'm wondering about using PHP inline with HTML. I am wondering why omitting semicolons works.

For example, why does the following code work?

```
<?php if(true): ?>
  <p>Hello World !!!</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Note: there is no semicolon after `endif` in `<?php endif ?>`

Comment: when closing conditionals in PHP with tags, you can omit the `;` - but it's not advised, I'd always terminate with a semi-colon

Comment: Because  the ending tag `?>` is automatically adding a semicolon.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php : _“The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. ”_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, I would always recommend including the semi-colon, but you're right, it can be dropped in this instance.

You may only drop the semi-colon after a statement when the statement is followed immediately by a closing PHP tag -- ie `?>`.

This is documented in the PHP documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

This is a feature from the earliest days of the language, aimed at making templated code slightly easier to read.

Unlike Javascript, there are no other circumstances where dropping the semi-colon is permitted.

Comment: I think OP means why `if(true):` work without semicolon. Like https://3v4l.org/kjQ02

Comment: @Mohammad not sure - OP has this in post `note: there is no semicolon after the <?php endif ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(true): ?>
  <p>Hello World !!!</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

reads as

```
<?php
if (true):
 echo "  <p>Hello World !!!</p>"
endif;
?>
```

which is a variation of

```
<?php
if (true) {
 echo "  <p>Hello World !!!</p>"
}
?>
```

which should only be used in a "html template" when no template engine is used
while a variation below is used in standard php files

semicolon should not be used in one-line code blocks as per standard (PSR https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) which is extremely valuable to follow

*not mentioning surrounding line breaks