# Can I get some simplified explanation about semi-colon use in php?

Tags: php, code-separation, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I have seen some articles explaining that a semi colon is not required in the last line of a PHP code due to the closing PHP tag (?>). Is this the case or is there any other theory around it?

Comment: Just from consistency point of view, I always include a `;`.  Is there any reason not to have it?

Comment: Never heard of dropping the last semi-colon. My IDE does not like it, and neither does `php -l` when using 7.3.

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52757180/14066311 and the doc https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semicolon is to denote end of the instruction, and that a new one may start.
When a closing tag is found, no new instructions are expected so it's technically not needed.

It's useful in cases like `<?= 'foobar' ?>` so you don't need to use a semicolon to echo out the string, but `<?= 'foobar'; ?>` works just as well.